# confused with result of joining the same table multiple times

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables (please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d04f/20)

I am having a difficult time visualizing what the difference is between the following:

```
select *
from TableA as a right outer join tableB as b on b.city1id = a.id
```

and

```
select *
from TableA as a right outer join tableB as b on b.city1id = a.id
left outer join tableB parent on parent.city2id = b.city1id
```

A right outer join is down between TableA and TableB, and the result of that is left outer joined with TableB again.

The result of running both queries is the same so I'm not sure what impact the left outer join has in this case.

Conceptually, I'm not sure what the difference is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i will explain [as i wrote that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258839/complications-building-result-using-group-by-given-data-set/16263397#16263397).

**Query 2**

```
 select *
    from TableA as a right outer join tableB as b on b.city1id = a.id
    left outer join tableB parent on parent.city2id = b.city1id
```

You can rewrite that query  like this

```
select *
from Tableb as b left outer join tablea as a on b.city1id = a.id
left  outer join tableb parent on parent.city2id = b.city1id
```

1st left outer join between tableB and table A does this

```
TableB( get all records ) and tableA matching records = call this result set as T
```

2nd left outer join between T and tableb does this

```
T ( get all records ) and tableb matching records
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258839/complications-building-result-using-group-by-given-data-set/16263397#16263397)

**Query 1**

```
select *
from TableA as a right outer join tableB as b on b.city1id = a.id
```

can be written like this

```
select *
from Tableb as b left outer join tablea as a on b.city1id = a.id
```

it just does this

1st left outer join between tableB and table A ( which is explained in the prev query)

```
 TableB( get all records ) and tableA matching records
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very good explanation. The only other thing that confuses me is set T and the result of `T (get all records) and tableb matching records` seems to be the same thing in this case - no? Take a look at the results of the query in both cases. Perhaps, I have overlooked something? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is: what is your *goal*. An outer join simply means that the side mentioned (left or right) is the side that records will be pulled from, then the opposite side will pull matching records, or null if no such matches are found.

Since you have `A right B left (B as parent)`, both joins are going to pull records from `B` and table `A` will only pull matches or null as required. Thus, your core query is all of table `B`, with table `A` being pulled in as you make matches and finally `B as parent` being pulled in as matches are found there.

Thus the two queries are going to both pull table `B` as the core of the response and table `B` controls the number of rows returned: all of B's rows. In your Fiddle, that is 7 rows.

(It is possible for an outer join to return *more* rows than the primary table (because multiple records on the optional side match a single required side record), but never less than the required table).